# What is an "indostânico"?

Tags: português-europeu, definição

In recent months, while reading Portuguese news articles, I have noticed the increasing popularity of the term "indostânico". What is the definition of "indostânico"? Has there been convergence towards a single definition?

Some use "indostânico" to refer to [South Asian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_subcontinent) peoples, i.e., Subcontinentals. For example, from a not-too-recent [article](https://observador.pt/especiais/imigracao-ilegal-ha-lojas-indianos-serem-exploradas-grupos-criminosos),

> [...] mercearias e frutarias propriedade de cidadãos oriundos da Península Indostânica, ou seja, de países como a Índia, o Paquistão e o Bangladesh

Is this the only definition?

Comment: It surprises me that you have read these articles in recent months. It was current usage in the English language before the second world war, when India and Pakistan were part of British Indochina. –

Comment: Yes, part of British Indochina.  Never heard ?

Comment: Although we can still find quite a few citations on [**British Indochina**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GDNBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&dq=%22British+Indochina%22&hl=pt-BR&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigxsfbnYKBAxWYFbkGHanNBG4Q6AF6BAgZEAI)  I couldn't find a definition of what countries that term comprised.

Comment: Around the end of the nineteenth century, most European colonies in Asia were either British or French and they used to be referred to as British Indochina (India, Pakistan, Bengladesh, Sri-Lanka, etc) and French Indochina (Vietnam, Cambodia, Laos, etc). Most of these countries became independent during the first half of the twentieth centrury.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Priberam's [Portuguese dictionary](https://dicionario.priberam.org/indost%C3%A2nico) gives two, related, definitions:

1. Related to *Indostão* (Hindustan), part of the Indian subcontinent which includes parts of India and Pakistan;
2. Related to *Hindustani,* an Indo-European language which enjoys wide diffusion in India.

It also records the variant *industânico.*

So it may refer either to something from that part of the Indian subcontinent, or to the language (which is generally called *Hindi* in India and *Urdu* in Pakistan).